# How to click the button which is placed in the same row with a <td /> containing specific text in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to click button of a row who has a `<td />` element containing a specific text in the same row. This is the architecture:

```
<tbody xpath="1">
 <tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class=" grdIslemlerYanYana" tabindex="0" style="width: 110.767px;">
   <div class="btn-group  btn-group-sm">
    <a class="btn btn-ajaxbutton btn-sm  btn-primary" data-ajaxsendmethod="post" data-url="..."> <i class="fa fa-search"></i> İncele </a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>766964</td>
  <td class="sorting_1">997149</td>
  <td>BLABLA</td>
  <td>Genel Destek Programı</td>
  <td>18/04/2017</td><td>Onaylandı</td>
  <td>Aktif</td>
  <td>BLABLA</td>
  <td style="display: none;">BLABLA</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr role="row" class="even">
  <td class=" grdIslemlerYanYana" tabindex="0" style="width: 110.767px;">
   <div class="btn-group  btn-group-sm">
    <a class="btn btn-ajaxbutton btn-sm  btn-primary" data-ajaxsendmethod="post" data-url="..."> 
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> İncele </a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>766964</td>
  <td class="sorting_1">997149</td>
  <td>BLABLA</td>
  <td>Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı</td>
  <td>10/01/2022</td>
  <td>Onaylandı</td>
  <td>Aktif</td>
  <td>BLABLA</td>
  <td style="display: none;">BLABLA</td>
  <td style="display: none;">3</td>
 </tr>

 <tr role="row" class="odd">
  <td class=" grdIslemlerYanYana" tabindex="0" style="width: 110.767px;">
   <div class="btn-group  btn-group-sm">
    <a class="btn btn-ajaxbutton btn-sm  btn-primary" data-ajaxsendmethod="post" data-url="...> 
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i> İncele 
    </a>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td>766964</td>
  <td class="sorting_1">997149</td><td>BLABlA</td>
  <td>İşletme Geliştirme Destek Programı</td>
  <td>20/01/2022</td><td>Onaylandı</td>
  <td>Aktif</td><td>BLABlA</td>
  <td style="display: none;">BLABlA</td>
  <td style="display: none;"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also I am attaching the SS here, showing what I am trying to do:

[image]

Format is like this(without any logic currently): `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(),'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]").click()`

I got very confused. I am trying to click the blue "INCELE" button which is inside the same row having a `<td />` containing string of "Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı" (I mean the second button on this page, but its place differs on different pages, therefore I should get the row with this text only).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the following XPath locator:

```py
//tr[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]//a[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]
```

Here we locating the `tr` parent element based on `td` with the specified text content and then we are locating the `a` button inside the parent `tr` element.
I guess the button element is the `a` element I used here. Otherwise it could be `div` element wrapping it...
So, the selenium command could be

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]//a[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]").click()
```

**UPD**
I will try to describe the logic better.
First of all the `//tr[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]` is to find the table row `tr` element based on some it child. And the `//a[contains(@class,'btn-primary')]` is to find a button inside that row.
So, in the `//tr[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]` expression the `//tr` is coming for element with `tr` tag name.
What else we know about this `tr`, this row? It contains (inside it) some `td` element with `Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı` text. This is what `[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]` comes for.
The dot `.` is coming to say "from here".
While regular `//` is telling you "search from the top of the DOM until you find the match, the `.//` is saying "search **inside** the current node until you find the match.
So, `//tr[.//td[contains(.,'Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı')]]` is actually saying "from the top of the DOM find element with `tr` tag name. Now, inside this `tr` element find `td` element containing text `Mikro ve Küçük İşletmelere Hızlı Destek Programı`.
Of cause, if during searching the DOM we find some `tr` but could not find inside it the `td` with predefined text we will continue to the next `tr` and search inside it until we find a match and return that node element or in case of no match nothing will be returned and Selenium will throw corresponding exception.

Comment: Yes it works. I looked here it is not understandable because of absence of the usage. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp I will try to understand the logic, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I added some more explanations. I hope now it is more clear. In case you need more explanations - I'm here

Comment: thank you. Can you also explain the dot "." additions inside your update? Then it will be more explanatory

Comment: Done. is now it clear enough?